# Trying to display last 10 calculations for a calculator

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I can get my program to display all the previous calculations however I want to limit it to the most recent 10.

Here is my problem...

```
Template.keypad.helpers({
    previous: function() { return previous.find(); }
});
```

I tried replacing it with this...

```
Template.keypad.helpers({
    previous: function() { return previous.sort({_id:1}).limit(10);}
});
```

However when I implement the second block of code it doesn't display any of the items in my collection.

What can I do to make this work? Thank you.

This is now my startup.js file

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if(Previous.find().count() === 0){
        Previous.insert({sum:"1+1", answer:"2"});
       }
    });
  Meteor.methods({
  previousInsert: function(arg1, operator, result){
    return Previous.insert({
      arg1:calculation,
      operator:"=",
      result:result,
      datetime: new Date(),
      //user: this.userId
    });
  },
});
}
```

This is the error I'm getting when i launch my program...
=> Errors prevented startup:
   While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.linux.x86_64):
   server/startup.js:8:18: server/startup.js: Unexpected token (8:18)
=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for your query should be like this:

```
Template.keypad.helpers({
  previous: function() { 
    return previous.find({}, {sort: {_id:1}, limit: 10}) 
});
```

However this alone will not give you the results you want as the _id field does not contain ascending integers.  Your best option would be to save a timestamp and sort by that field.

I'd suggest you follow the convention of Capitalizing your Collection names, so it is easier to distinguish between previous (your helper method name) and Previous (the collection).

Following the principle of "Do not trust the client" I would add autovalues in Meteor Methods on the server like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  previousInsert: function(arg1, arg2, operator, result){
    return Previous.insert({
      arg1:arg1,
      arg2:arg2,
      operator:arg1,
      result:result,
      datetime: new Date(),
      //user: this.userId   
    });
  }, 
});
```

Then call on the client like this:

```
Meteor.call('previousInsert', 2, 4, '+', 6)
```

And retrieve the last 10 with:

```
Previous.find({}, {sort: {datetime:-1}, limit: 10})
```

If you are using the Accounts package uncomment the user: this.userId line in previousInsert and you can change your filter to:

```
Previous.find({user: Meteor.userId()}, {sort: {datetime:-1}, limit: 10})
```

And allow each user to view only their own previous 10 calculations

If you do not want to user Meteor Methods for your inserts, you can look [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#autovalue).

Here is a minimal [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/rZDWaWMaZcu8EGLmm/calc) example of what you are trying to acheive.
Note that I **do not recommend using eval like this**.  However this is not relevant to the original question raised here.

Comment: How could I add a timestamp to each id?

Comment: You don't add a timestamp to the _id field, it's a new field.  I'll add it to the answer

Comment: the javascript api does not support that fluent api calling style you are copying from python examples

Comment: I have no idea where to put all of that... I put the meteor method in my startup.js file inside the if(Meteor.isServer) statement.
I then added the Previous.find in the keypad helpers however I don't know what exactly to edit in the meteor method to make it suitable for my program. Where should i call on the meteor method?

Comment: I have added some more to my question above which shows the error i'm receiving now and the code i'm having trouble with

Comment: ahh, I missed the object syntax inside Meteor.method.  Needs to be Meteor.method( { ... } ).  updated above.  You have it in the right place, in the Meteor.isServer block, but check your variable names are correct

Comment: What variables do I have to change? I'm not getting the error anymore (THANKYOU) but it's still not displaying the recent calculations... :/

Comment: Edited my question above with the code I currently have. Did I edit the variables correctly? What else do I need to change to make it display the items?